# Broadcast receiver in the manifest file stops receiving after a while

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am developing an andoid application that blocks all outgoing calls to a particular number.For this purpose,I have registered a receiver in the manifest file.The application works fine initially and the receiver reveives the NEW_OUTGOING_CALL intent.However,as soon as my device goes to sleep mode,the receiver stops working and doesn't work until and unless I open the application again.Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue? Thanks 
Below is my code.

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)){
         String number=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
         if(number.equals("022344")){        
             setResultData(null);
             Toast.makeText(context, "Call to " + number + " is not allowed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }

    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: Use [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Comment: But can u tell me the reason that why is this happening?

Comment: Is this an inner class of an `Activity` or a stand-alone class?

Comment: Stand alone..my activity has nothing..

Comment: post your manifest please

Answer (score -1):

Broadcast receiver is only guaranteed to keep the phone awake for the duration of the onReceive method. If you need to do work beyond that method, you need to aquire/manage another wake lock.

A Commonsware library exists for this purpose. Have a look at: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful/blob/master/README.markdown

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14332321/onreceive-method-not-opening-application-while-device-is-in-sleep-mode)

Otherwise you have create a class that extends [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) .The purpose is to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other applications to use.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I don't want it to work when the phone is in sleep mode. I Just want it to work when the phone is active again.

Comment: @Soham If you look at the code you will see that OP is only doing work in the `onReceive()` method. He is just calling `setResultData()` to block certain outgoing calls. There is no reason to use a `Service`. This code is perfectly fine.

Comment: @DavidWasser I suggest to use service as I thought he wants to run it after also the phone is in the sleepmode. Can you please give the answer to this question what he has asked for other than doing some downvoting,so that I can learn also something.